# Is there any way I can make this small piece of code shorter? (Python)

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

```
first  = [0, 0, 0, 0]
second = [0, 0, 0, 0]
third  = [0, 0, 0, 0]
fourth = [0, 0, 0, 0]

while 0 in first and 0 in second and 0 in third and 0 in fourth:
```

The lists at the top begin with each value holding 0. As the program progress' I plan to change the values in the list from 0 to other numbers. Effectively, I want to know if there is way to re-write the 'while' statement to check if 0 is in any list, WITHOUT the long chain of 'while not in __ and not in __' etc.
Cheers

Comment: 0 in any list, so if only one list has a 0 and every other value in every other list is another number, you still want it to return True? What would be an explicit input example of your result being False?

Comment: Do you want to check if there is a 0 in any list or if there is a 0 present in each list?

Comment: FYI - You can only accept one answer. I noticed the accept answer change places a few times. Thought I'd let you know.

Comment: While your example `while 0 in first and 0 in second and 0 in third and 0 in fourth:` means "0 in each list", in the text to your question you say _"...check if 0 is in any list..."_. "each" and "any" are very different things. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while all(0 in i for i in [first,second,third,fourth]):
   ...
```

and If you want to check if any of the lists contain 0, do this:

```
while any(0 in i for i in [first,second,third,fourth]):
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate/combine all your lists and check truthyness:

```
while not all(first+second+third+fourth):
```

This checks for any False-y value and returns True if there is a 0.

Comment: Not what OP wants. seems he wants to check `0 in first` **and** `0 in second` .... This will give True if there is *any* 0

Comment: @RafaelC  "...to check if 0 is in any list". Am I missing something?

Comment: I think your answer is OK. It answers the question "check if 0 is in **any** list". But OP _example_ is the opposite: `0 in first and 0 in second and 0 in third and 0 in fourth` checks that "0 is in **every** list". It is just that the OP question is confusing AND @U9-Forward has strong feelings about his interpretation.

Comment: @AGNGazer The fist example is checking for all

Comment: @U9-Forward Why did you add the second example to your answer? It essentially is a variation of dfundako's answer

Comment: @AGNGazer I am just giving another example for the OP because maybe somewhere else he wants to use it

Comment: @U9-Forward Oh. _That_'s why... And why is _this_ answer wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
while 0 in first + second + third + fourth:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `map`

```
ls = [first, second, third, fourth]
func = lambda x: 0 in x

while all(map(func, ls)):
    #dostuff
```

---

Use `all` if you want `0 in first and 0 in second and ...`. Use `any` if you want `0 in first` or `0 in second` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
while not any(map(all, [first, second, ...])):
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.